# Updating TableLayout from another class

Tags: android

I am really new to android and I have been reading on stackeroverflow, that we need to pass the Context when updating TableLayout from another class.  But I am not trying to update the TableLayout directly from another class; i am trying to update it by calling a method in the MainActivity.  And this method has all the update code.

Here is what I have:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public void addTableRow(String company, Integer shares, float p, float f) {

     TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablelayout);
     TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);

     //does a bunch of stuff here
     //then does some formatting

     companyName.setText(company);
     companyShares.setText(shares.toString());
     dailyChange.setText(String.format("%.2f", p));
     dailyChangeToPortfolio.setText(String.format("%.2f", f));

     tr.addView(companyName);
     tr.addView(companyShares);
     tr.addView(dailyChange);
     tr.addView(dailyChangeToPortfolio);

     tl.addView(tr);
}
```

}

In my other class I have

```
public class UpdateStock {

    public void startUpdate(){
        MainActivity m = new MainActivity();
        m.addTableRow("CSCO", 10, 5.555f, 6.666f);
    }
}
```

But it errors on me.  Any suggestions to get this to work would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Intent to pass data into a new Activity:

```
public static class MyRowData implements Serializable {

    String company;
    Integer shares;
    float p;
    float f;

    public MyRowData(String company, Integer shares, float p, float f) {
        this.company = company;
        this.shares = shares;
        this.p = p;
        this.f = f;
    }
}

public class UpdateStock {

    public void startUpdate(){
        MyRowData rowData = new MyRowData("CSCO", 10, 5.555f, 6.666f);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("MY_DATA", rowData);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    MyRowData getRowData()
    {
        return (MyRowData)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MY_DATA");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion is way over my understanding.  Is there another means to accomplish this by passing Context?

Comment: I am not sure what is the relationship between your 2 classes. Who creates `updateStock` (you should really rename it to UpdateStock), what is the relationship between it and the `MainActivity`? You can always use a static array to save your data instead.

Comment: The passing of the data is not the issue I dont think.  It is that within the UpdateStock class, when i call the startUpdate() it should call the addTableRow() within MainActivity. And MainActivity has all the update code to update the table.

Comment: The question is how UpdateStock  gets a reference to MainActivity then? If you only have one activity it will be easy. Otherwise, you need to take care of lifecycle events.